# Axiom of dependent choice in König's lemma

Tags: proof-explanation, axioms

Consider proof 1 from König's lemma from wikipedia: [https://proofwiki.org/wiki/König%27s_Tree_Lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_Tree_Lemma)

At the end, they say they apply the axiom of dependent choice. I wonder on which set we apply the axiom: on the vertices of the $T$, or on our set $\{t_0,t_1,\dots\}$ which we have shown is indeed infinite. If it is the latter, then what relation did they use? If it's the former, same question really.. I'm confused because the specific relation of having inifnitely many descendants, and having a finite amount of ancestors which we can't take into acount anymore, doesn't seem to be true for all $t\in T$, so that's why I think it's the latter. But what's the relation? Is it that $t_iR t_j$ if $j=i+1$?

Comment: How about the set of all nodes with infinitely many descendants, and the relation $sRt\iff t\text{ is a child of }s$? Does that work?

Comment: Yes, that works! I got help in the chat, and that is exactly what someone else told me as well. So this set exists by axiom of subsets. You might additionally want to show that this set is infinite, and that there will be no loopes in our sequence (which is true because we have a tree), and then the argument is finished.